# link inside pdf in new browser Window

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

My project, generating pdfs, is almost finished.
I am facing a problem that I can't figure out myself:
How can I manage to make links inside my pdfs to open in a new window while viewing the pdf?

I am generate=ing pdf's using tcpdf, Here is my code in which I am showing my dynamic links that need to open in new tab or window :

```
 <?php if(($appval['name'])== 'PDF'){?>
 <dt ><?php echo stripslashes($appval['name']); ?></dt>
        <dd><a href=<?php echo stripslashes($appval['value']); ?>><?php echo stripslashes($appval['value']); ?></a></dd>
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit @beaver , 
Is the above issue can be sortout ?